# What is the pythonic way of specifying a minimal module version?

Tags: python, dependencies, packaging

I'm writing a Python script where one of its imported modules needs to be at least version `x.y.z`.

```
import pandas as pd

# Check the pandas version
_pdversion = map(lambda x: int(x), pd.__version__.split('.'))
if _pdversion[1] < 18:
    # Not sure the most sensible exception class..
    raise Exception("ERROR: you need pandas > version 0.18")
```

Is there a standard way to check for a minimal version at runtime? Or is this discouraged, in favour of specification at the package level and configure-time?

Comment: setup.py requires is probably the best way to go

Answer (score 0):

I think the most pythonic way would be to specify it in a requirements.txt file, and keep everything in a virtual environment.

Or:

```
import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.require("requests==2.11.1")
import requests
```